# "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread" when using Thread.sleep(..)

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I have written a simple code to simulate the problem I have when I use ExecuterService to spawn multiple threads to do a load test.

Code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestThreads {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     class Testing implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch(InterruptedException e1) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Running the inner thread");
                }
            };
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.start(); 
            System.out.println("After the thread has been started");
        }

    };         
    ExecutorService execService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        Testing testing = new Testing();
        execService.execute(testing);
    }
    execService.shutdown();
    try {
        execService.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

When I run the code I get multiple `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread` exceptions. If I remove the `Thread.sleep(5000)` from the run method of the Testing class, the problem resolves. I would like to know why is that so? How does the ExecutorService behave when a thread in the pool goes to sleep (does it add another thread to the pool)?

Comment: You're simply overloading your system with *1 million threads*, which is insanely high. Not sleeping means they are terminated to make space for new threads.

Comment: Looks like you are making 20 threads and your JVM isn't set up with enough memory to support that many.  When you remove the sleep then the threads complete their computation before too many threads are created.  Does your program work if you change your threadpool to have say 2 threads instead of 20?

Comment: @kenney its a threadpool so even though he is making 1M requests for threads wont it only do 20 at a given time?

Comment: No it doesn't work if I run it with 2 threads in the threadpool, and I have 4 processors available (Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors() returns 4)

Comment: @Kenney, I agree with pwilmot- to my understanding, if the thread pool size is limited to 20, it means it won't spawn 1000000 threads at the same time, and why does it work when I remove the sleep?

Comment: Oh its that you are making a thread inside of your run function.

Comment: checkout http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/java-thread-pool-example-using-executors-and-threadpoolexecutor.html

Comment: If you could get this code to run, then what problem would it solve?  That is to say, why do you want to use an `ExecutorService` to launch a million threads?  Or, forget about the ExecutorService.  How about just, why do you want a million threads?

Comment: @jameslarge I am trying to do a load test, is that not how I have to do it?

Comment: Well, if the system that you are testing is the same one that is running the code, I would say that your testing has revealed a significant limit.  If, on the other hand, your example runs as a network client, trying to stress some _other_ system, then maybe you're going to need more than one client machine to create a sufficient load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only manage the `Testing` runnable with the ExecutorService, which makes sure that only 20 instances of `Testing` are running at a time. These threads complete really quickly, because all they do is start another thread with an anonymous subclass of `Runnable` named `TestThreads$1` and then exit.

You would see one million lines of `"After the thread has been started"` in your console, indicating the `for` loop has completed,
and then after about 5 seconds you would see one million lines of `"Running the inner thread"` indicating the nested thread has completed, *if* your system allows to run a million threads.

So, all you are limiting is the *rate at which new threads are started*, not the number of threads.

By default, each thread gets a stack of 512kb (which you can change with the `-Xss` commandline option to `java`).
For a million threads, that means you would need 1000000 * 512kb = **448Gb** of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Right now for every thread that your threadpool creates its calls the run function.  Each run you are also creating an additional new thread.  So you will have 20 active threads + 1 thread for each thread that has already run and these inner threads aren't using a threadpool to help with cleaning up resources.

This code should work if you don't create the inner threads by removing

```
Thread t = new Thread(r);
t.start();
```